# Simple modrewrite, how does a link appear?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

When you use modrewrite to rewrite your urls, when does the rewrite occur. Will the user be able to see the url before rewrite, when hovering over the link? When they hover over a link will their browser display the rewritten url or the url before it was modified with modrewrite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mod_rewrite acts on the server side, meaning that apache rewrites incoming URLs before responding to the request. Any HTML links you add to a page will point to the URL you entered, as mod_rewrite doesn't modify any outgoing data.

Answer (score 2):

The rewrite is done in the server so the user will never know,
PHP also doesn't know what link its pointing to only the script file

Answer (score 1):

The rewrite occurs when Apache has parsed the request - before the PHP interpreter has been started.